Environment for verbatim boxes
I want to achieve verbatim boxes with different colors. I want something like this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}
   I want this to be verbatim and colored
\end{verbbox}
\colorbox{lightgray}{\parbox{\textwidth-0.5em}{\theverbbox}}

\end{document}

this easily prints a box with whatever i need. However, I donẗ want to type the \colorbox all over again, so I would create an environment:
\newenvironment{gbox}
{\begin{verbbox}}
{\end{verbbox}
\colorbox{lightgray}{\parbox{\textwidth-0.5em}{\theverbbox}}}

however, the following does not compile with the error "File ended while scanning use of \next":
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newenvironment{gbox}
{\begin{verbbox}}
{\end{verbbox}
\colorbox{lightgray}{\parbox{\textwidth-0.5em}{\theverbbox}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{gbox}
     I want this to be verbatim and colored
\end{gbox}
\end{document}

What am I doing wrong?

You should use \verbbox and \endverbbox to define a new environment. Additionally you cannot use \parbox{\textwidth-0.5em} unless you load package calc. Here an example, that does not need calc:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}% to visualize the text area
\newenvironment{gbox}
{\par\verbbox}
{\endverbbox
\noindent\colorbox{lightgray}{\parbox{\dimeval{\textwidth-2\fboxsep}}{\theverbbox}}\par}
\begin{document}
\begin{gbox}
     I want this to be verbatim and colored
\end{gbox}
\end{document}



I'd do it with fancyvrb.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newsavebox{\gboxbox}
\newenvironment{gbox}{%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{lrbox}{\gboxbox}
  \begin{minipage}{\dimeval{\columnwidth-2\fboxsep}}
  \begin{Verbatim}%
}{%
  \end{Verbatim}\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}\noindent
  \colorbox{lightgray}{\usebox{\gboxbox}}%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
}

\begin{document}

Some text before the verbatim box.
Some text before the verbatim box.
Some text before the verbatim box.
Some text before the verbatim box.

\begin{gbox}
I want this to be verbatim and colored
I want this to be verbatim and colored
I want this to be verbatim and colored
I want this to be verbatim and colored
\end{gbox}

Some text after the verbatim box.
Some text after the verbatim box.
Some text after the verbatim box.
Some text after the verbatim box.

\end{document}


You should also have a look at tcolorbox. For instance,
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage{none}{}{}

\newtcblisting{gbox}[1][lightgray]{
  colback=#1,
  listing only,
  listing options={language=none,basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=flexible},
}

\begin{document}

Some text before the verbatim box.
Some text before the verbatim box.
Some text before the verbatim box.
Some text before the verbatim box.

\begin{gbox}
I want this to be verbatim and colored
I want this to be verbatim and colored
I want this to be verbatim and colored
I want this to be verbatim and colored
\end{gbox}

Some text after the verbatim box.
Some text after the verbatim box.
Some text after the verbatim box.
Some text after the verbatim box.


\begin{gbox}[red!20]
I want this to be verbatim and colored
I want this to be verbatim and colored
I want this to be verbatim and colored
I want this to be verbatim and colored
\end{gbox}

Some text after the verbatim box.
Some text after the verbatim box.
Some text after the verbatim box.
Some text after the verbatim box.

\end{document}


You can customiza the boxes at will.

For this purpose I'd personally use tcolorbox, but that is already covered in @egreg's answer. So for this reason I'll just advertise one of my own packages which can also be used.
The enverb package allows you to wrap verbatim material in whatever normal TeX command you want after it's been collected in an environment. Defining environments is pretty straight forward, just use \enverb as the last command in the begin block and \enverbBody in the end block to insert the collected contents. With the default setup of the end-of-line contents you can also forward the body to another verbatim environment in place.
The following shows both approaches.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enverb}% also loads expkv-def for key=value setup
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ekvdefinekeys{verbboxed}
  {
     store   color = \verbboxedColor
    ,initial color = lightgray
    ,eskip   above = \verbboxedAbove
    ,initial above = \medskipamount
    ,eskip   below = \verbboxedBelow
    ,initial below = \medskipamount
    % any unknown key without a value is considered a color as well
    ,unknown noval = \ekvset{verbboxed}{color={#2}}
  }

\newenvironment{verbboxed}
  {\enverb{bol=\hangindent=2em\relax,eol=\par,key-set=verbboxed}}
  {%
    \par
    \vskip\verbboxedAbove
    \noindent
    \colorbox{\verbboxedColor}
      {%
        \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}
          \ttfamily\frenchspacing
          \raggedright
          \enverbBody
        \end{minipage}%
      }%
    \par
    \vskip\verbboxedBelow
  }

\newenvironment{simpleboxed}
  {\enverb{key-set=verbboxed}}
  {%
    \par
    \vskip\verbboxedAbove
    \noindent
    \colorbox{\verbboxedColor}
      {%
        \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}
          \enverbListing{verbatim}{}%
        \end{minipage}%
      }%
    \par
    \vskip\verbboxedBelow
  }

\begin{document}
Some text above.
\begin{verbboxed}[below=\bigskipamount]
  I  want this to be \verbatim and \colored. Though I ask myself what happens on long lines?
  Another line ends up where?
\end{verbboxed}
That looks good, but setting it up was so cumbersome. We can be simpler though:
\begin{simpleboxed}
  I  want this to be \verbatim and \colored. Though I ask myself what happens on long lines?
  Another line ends up where?
\end{simpleboxed}
Hm, long lines don't look as good. Luckily there are more sophisticated listings
packages like \texttt{listings} that can be used (and are usable in
\texttt{tcblisting}) that are easy to setup and don't overprint.
\end{document}


